# Hibernate Criterai API. JOINs

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

It is possible to construct Criteria query for this SQL:

```
SELECT P.This FROM Position P INNER JOIN PersonOnPosition PP ON PP.Tail = P.This WHERE PP.Tail IS NOT NULL
```

I want to port Hibernate Criteria to custom SQL dialect (custom ECM framework), but I have troubles with `JOIN`'.

Thanks.

Comment: @JulienLanglois I expected this kind of question :) I don't tried anything. I build custom implementation of Hibernate Criteria API (for custom ECM framework). So I ported most of the functionality from Hibernate Criteria, but a have trouble with `JOIN`'s

Comment: So you haven't even built the entities yet?  I'd recommend doing those first then seeing how far you get.

Answer (score 1):

As @Julien Langlois pointed out, this depends on your Entity definitions.

Assuming you defined a relation like

```
@Entity
class PersonOnPosition {
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="Tail")
  Position position;
}
```

you can go with

```
session.createCriteria(PersonOnPosition.class, "PP")
    .createAlias("position", "P")
    .setProjection(Property.forName("P.This"))
    .add(Property.forName("PP.position").isNotNull())
    .list();
```

If you didn't define the relation, you can achieve the same result using a subquery:

```
DetachedCriteria personOnPositionWithTail = DetachedCriteria.forClass(PersonOnPosition.class, "PP")
    .setProjection(Property.forName("PP.Tail"))
    .add(Property.forName("PP.Tail").isNotNull());
session.createCriteria(Position.class, "P")
    .setProjection(Property.forName("P.This"))
    .add(Property.forName("P.This").in(personOnPositionWithTail))
    .list();
```

Comment: This might be a misleading response. If his entities have appropriate associations defined, he only needs to add the criteria. See [Criteria Query Associations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-association). A subquery can be less performant.

Comment: @JulienLanglois yes you are right. I was under the impression that it was clear (to the asker) how to define the query if a relation was in place - but that might not be the case. So I added the "obvious" approach. Thanks!